# Leaflet 1 million points

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

We have a project where we need to put a LOT of points on a country-scale leaflet map when zoomed out (no cluster markers - need to see all the points).

We have the coordinates for each point so could put them in as markers but that would be sssslllloooowwww.

At low zoom, when most of the points would show, there is no need for them to be interactive or clickable, so is there a a better way of getting them from co-ordinates to the map quickly?

We're thinking maybe something like a transparent png - but how would we generate it from our coordinates, and then attach it to the map? The points don't change often so caching is not a problem. Is there something else that is fast that we can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at vector tiles for your points: https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles

Comment: Perhaps https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas will work.

Comment: Thanks guys!
@user2441511 your suggestion looks especially promising... it looks like it uses quadtrees - do you know if it can take geohashes rather than lon/lat pairs? (to keep the json shorter)

Comment: My 13" laptop screen has  about 1 million pixels.

Comment: ha - good point well made @gboffi .

Comment: Why not a semi-transparent heat map derived from point densities? A variation on this idea, plot all the points over the map using quasi-transparent discs, overlapping would create a "shadow" over the map, more or less equivalent to the heat map. Cannot say which is faster.